# confused Lucene StringField

Tags: search, lucene, document

I want to read some documents from the index has been created, and then put them in another index。But I can not retrieve these documents in “another index”
oh,the documets just have StringField 。。
..someboy can  help me

the code:

```
public static void test() throws IOException{
    IndexWriterConfig conf=new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_43, new MapbarAnalyzer(TokenizerModle.COMMON));
    conf.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE);
    conf.setMaxBufferedDocs(10000);
    LogByteSizeMergePolicy policy=new LogByteSizeMergePolicy();
    policy.setNoCFSRatio(1.0);
    policy.setUseCompoundFile(true);
    conf.setMergePolicy(policy);
    Directory d=new RAMDirectory();
    IndexWriter iw=new IndexWriter(d, conf);
    Document doc=new Document();
    doc.add(new StringField("type", "5B0", Store.YES));
    iw.addDocument(doc);
    iw.close();

    IndexReader r=DirectoryReader.open(d);
    IndexSearcher is=new IndexSearcher(r);
    Query q=new TermQuery(new Term("type","5B0"));
    TopDocs docs=is.search(q, 10);
    System.out.println(docs.totalHits);



    Directory d1=new RAMDirectory();
    IndexWriter iw1=new IndexWriter(d1, conf);
    int maxdoc=r.maxDoc();
    for(int i=0;i<maxdoc;i++){
        Document doc0=r.document(i);
        iw1.addDocument(doc0);
    }
    iw1.close();
    IndexReader r1=DirectoryReader.open(d1);
    IndexSearcher is1=new IndexSearcher(r1);
    Query q1=new TermQuery(new Term("type","5B0"));
    TopDocs docs1=is1.search(q1, 10);
    System.out.println(docs1.totalHits);


}
```

Comment: If you simply don't get any documents back from your query it might depend on the analyzer you're using. What does the `MapbarAnalyzer` do exactly? Remember that the term query is not analyzed, thus you have to search for a token that's exactly the same as one in your index in order to find results.

Comment: hi,javana .For 'StringField' lucene directly call 'StringTokenStream',so I think What does the MapbarAnalyzer do is irrelevant.And I tried 'KeywordAnalyzer StopAnalyzer' ,its the same issue.What I am confused is original doc can search results but rewrited this doc to index is cant't

Answer (score 0):

You can try to compare what's the differences between these two index/document/query
It turns out doc0's field is set with a "tokenized" attribute.

change the code like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<maxdoc;i++){
    Document doc0=r.document(i);
    Field f1 = (Field) doc0.getField("type");
    f1.fieldType().setTokenized(false);
    iw1.addDocument(doc0);
}
```

and you can get the result from another index.

But I have no idea why FieldType getting from InderReader changed...